# How could I shorten my code in this old graded homework?

Tags: python, python-3.x, homework

I have this old graded homework, I am looking how to improve the or shorten the code, I have some lines with over 200 chars.

> ```
> to_pairs(network) does the opposite.
>
> n_friends(network, n) gets a network (the second presentation) and returns a set of names of persons that have exactly n friends.
>
> lonely(network) returns a set of names of people with only a single friend.
>
> most_known(network) returns the name of the person with most friends.
>
> common_friends(network, name1, name2) returns a set of common friends of the two persons.
>
>
>
> by_n_friends(network) returns a dictionary with keys from 1 to len(mreza) - 1 and the corresponding sets of people with that number
> ```
>
> of friends. For instance, for the small network, the function must
>   return {1: {"D"}, 2: {"A", "B"}, 3: {"C"}}. See the example for the
>   large network in the tests.
>
> ```
> suggestions(network) returns a list of pairs that are not friends but have at least one common friend. The pair must be sorted
> ```
>
> alphabetically (e.g. ("Ana", "Berta") and not ("Berta", "Ana")).
>
> ```
> clique(network, names) returns True if all persons from the group names know each other, and False otherwise.
>
> most_commons(network) returns the pair with the most mutual friends.
>
>
>
> strangers(network, names) returns True if the group names contains absolute strangers - not even one pair knows each other -, and False
> ```
>
> otherwise.
>
> ```
> is_cover(network, names) returns True if the group "covers" the entire network in the sense that every person in the network is either
> ```
>
> in the group or is a friend with someone in the group.
>
> ```
> triangles(network) computes the number of "triangles" - triplets of people who know each other.
>
>
>
> minimal_cover(network) returns the smallest set of names that cover the network (in the sense described at function is_cover, above).
> ```

Here's the explanation and here's a picture. 
Big network: 
[image]

Small network:
[image]

And here's my code:

```
def to_dict(pairs):
    from collections import defaultdict
    paired = defaultdict(set)
    for k, v in pairs:
        paired[k].add(v)
        paired[v].add(k)
    return dict(paired)
def to_pairs(network):
    return {(k, v) for k, vs in network.items() for v in vs if k < v}
def n_friends(network, n):
    return {k for k , v in network.items() if len(v) == n}
def lonely(network):
    return {k for k, v in network.items() if len(v) == 1}
def most_known(network):
    return max(network, key=lambda k: len(network[k]))
def common_friends(network, name1, name2):
    return set(network[name1].intersection(network[name2]))
def by_n_friends(network):
    return {x: {k for k, v in network.items() if len(v) == x} for x in range(1, len(network))}
def clique(network, names):
    import itertools as it
    return {tuple(sorted(y)) for y in (it.combinations(names, 2))} <= {tuple(sorted(x)) for x in to_pairs(network)}
def most_commons(network):
    friends = {}
    for pair in to_pairs(network):
        for elem in pair:
            friends.setdefault(elem, set()).update(pair)
    return next(iter(({pair for pair in to_pairs(network) if ({pair: len(friends[pair[0]] & friends[pair[1]]) for pair in to_pairs(network)})[pair] == (max({pair: len(friends[pair[0]] & friends[pair[1]]) for pair in to_pairs(network)}.values()))})))

def strangers(network,names):
    import itertools as it
    return not(bool([(x,y) for x in set(it.permutations(names, 2)) for y in to_pairs(network) if x == y]))
def suggestions(network):
    return {tuple(sorted([k,k1])) for k in network.keys() for k1 in network.keys() if k not in network[k1] and len(network[k] & network[k1]) != 0 and k != k1}
def is_cover(network, names):
    return not([k for k in network.keys() if k not in names and network[k] & names == set()])
def triangles(network):
    return len({tuple(sorted([k1,k2,k3])) for k1 in network.keys() for k2 in network.keys() for k3 in network.keys() if k1!=k2 and k2!=k3 and k1!=k3 and(k1 in network[k3] and k2 in network[k3] and k1 in network[k2])})
def minimal_cover(network):
    import itertools as it
    if len(network) <= 4:
        bar1 = list(map(set, list(network.keys())))
        for st in bar1:
            if is_cover(network,st):
                return st
    else:
        bar = list(map(set, sorted(it.combinations(list(network), 3))))
        for st in bar:
            if is_cover(network, st):
                return st
```

The homework is followed with unit tests made by the professor, I will not post them. 
Edit: The goal was to done the home work with one liners.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have to operate under the assumption that no data can be saved? I mean: could you for example save the count of each person's friends and use it later? You're repeating quite a lot of code as it is now. For instance `lonely` could be written as a call to `n_friends(network, 1)`.

Comment: @ChatterOne , oh no, I didn't realize that. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Longest lines can be rewritten thus:

```
def are_friends(network, a, b):
    return a in network[b]

def clique(network, names):
    """
    returns True if all persons from the group names know each other, 
    and False otherwise.
    """
    return all(are_friends(network, a, b) 
        for a, b in it.combinations(names, 2))

def most_commons(network):
    """the pair with the most mutual friends"""
    return max(to_pairs(network), 
        key = lambda p: len(common_friends(network, p[0], p[1])))

def suggestions(network):
    def has_common_friend(a, b):
        return len(common_friends(network, a, b)) > 0

    return [(a, b) 
        for a, b in it.combinations(sorted(network.keys()), 2) 
        if not are_friends(network, a, b) 
            and has_common_friend(a, b)]

def triangles(network):
    """the number of triplets of people who know each other."""
    return len(t for t in it.combinations(network.keys(), 3) if clique(t))
```

Reusing functions as also suggested by ChatterOne and more consistent use of `itertools.combinations`.

Also

- Use built-in functions s.a. [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all), `max` whenever appropriate.
- Remove unnecessary parens.
- Divide long function calls and list comprensions.

to prevent lines getting too long.